# Disabling vscode intellisense for only one word or phrase?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to create a "blacklist" of words or phrases that get ignored by vscode intellisense?

Right now I get an autocomplete suggestion every time I type `error`, which results in a small code block that I do not want, as I only want the word `error` itself.

I'm not looking to disable intellisense entirely, only on this one instance of a particular phrase, and was wondering if it's possible to do that.

Comment: just press Esc don't Tab or Enter or just type any other character

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, I want a way to disable certain words from triggering intellisense suggestions entirely.

Comment: any extension can be a CompletionItemProvider, It you want this type of functionality you must file a feature request for VSC, at the moment it is not part of VSC